# как реализовать механизм резервного копирования дифференциальной части одного файла

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, csharpcodeprovider

задача - резервное копирование выбранных файлов.
сейчас механизм моей программы примерно такой.
пользователь ,через тривью помечает папки и файлы для бекапа.а так же выбирает время начала и частоту бекапа.

когда наступает выбранное время ,делаю снепшот всего диска( AlphaVSS), монтирую снепшот и забираю с него выбранные файлы. Это позволяет мне корректно забирать открытые файлы и базы данных без остановки сервера (на пример).

так же, перед каждым копированием файлов, кроме первого раза, я проверяю ,редактировался ли файл после последнего бекапа,и забираю повторно только те файлы которые изменились или на пример появились в выбранной пользователем папке.
Но мне нужно прийти к варианту, при котором, первый раз я забираю файл целиком, а каждый следующий раз, забираю только изменившуюся часть файла.то есть только те несколько байт которые непосредственно добавились к файлу или изменились в нём.

хотелось бы реализовать это с помощью  AlphaVSS или API VSS, но поиски инфы по теме не увенчались успехом.

**буду рад любой подсказке или пинку в нужном направлении**.

потратил на это уже кучу времени, и всё безрезультатно. Задумываюсь уже о написании некого метода, который будет создавать маску файла, что то вроде --- первый бит файла=1 ,второй бит файла =1 , 3 бит файла =0 и так далее, а потом изменившиеся файлы сверять с этой маской и записывать отдельные биты с адресами на пример в базу данных . Ну и на выходе, при восстановлении  из резервного  копирования, подменять биты по записанным адресам , на релевантные данные в выбранный период времени.
Но что то мне подсказывает, что такая процедура займёт кучу времени ,если файл будет даже несколько сот мегабайт

Comment: допустим, у вас есть файл на гигабайт. Копируем его и добавляем в начало файла 1 байт. Но есть все байты по индексу сместятся. Вам надо найти именно что один байт добавлен или вам будет проще весь файл перебекапить?

Comment: Диффы имели бы смысл при очень медленной скорости передачи данных. _займёт кучу времени_ - если кратко, то да.

Comment: скорость интернета в моём случае не имеет решающего значения. дифы нужны для экономии места. на пример файл pst может весить 10-20 гигов. и бекапя каждый день сто машин   с сохранением предыдущих версий не каких ресурсов не напасёшься.